# yii2 swift mail is going to spam

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

```
my config is 
     'mail' => [
     'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
     'useFileTransport' => false,
     'transport' => [
     'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
     'host' => 'cpanelhost',  
     'username' => 'cpanel mail username',
     'password' => 'cpanelpassword',
     'port' => '465',
     'encryption' => 'tls',
     ]


and my model,

       $message  = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/new', ['status' => $model->status,'note' => 
        $model->description,'process' => $model->job_process_id])
        ->setFrom(['example@gmail.com' => 'title'])
        ->setTo($Jobmodel->email)
        ->setSubject('Status Change');
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('name', 'value');
        $message->send();
```

this mail is going to spam.iam using php 7.2. i change config mail =>   to  mailer but still going to spam .if i delete that config not prevent mail,actually that config is not require for send mail,mail is going without use the config but its going to spam.

Answer (score 0):

your email go into spam is not because of Swiftmailer, is because of your email hosting provider.

You may consider using 3rd party email service like Mailgun, SendGrid, Mandrill, SparkPost etc...

Activate their trial and use the SMTP settings like user and password (e.g. API key) provided by them, follow their documentation.

However, it will not guarantee your email not going to SPAM as well, it depends on many factors, e.g. your email content, also the receiver's email service provider's SPAM rules.